# how to make a redraw on frame with nodewebkit in javascript?

Tags: javascript, webview, repaint, node-webkit, redraw

So I charge a webpage in a frame nodewebkit and when it's done, the web didn't redraw my frame, if I do it with my cursor the content come back, I tried this solution but it still doesn't work, any ideas?

```
window.onload = function() {
      var win = document.getElementById('wv1');
      win.style.display='none';
      win.offsetHeight;
      win.style.display='block';
    };
```

you can also check the file on github:

https://github.com/radjivC/Whatsapp-desktop/blob/master/app/index.html

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `window.onload` will work. Try the using the following instead.

```html
// Load native UI library
var gui = require('nw.gui'); //or global.window.nwDispatcher.requireNwGui() (see https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/issues/707)

// Get the current window
var win = gui.Window.get();

win.on('loaded', function(){
  //Your code here
});
```